# Why can materials like sandpaper deform hard metals?

Tags: friction

I don't have much of a physics background, so my assumptions might be somewhat incorrect. But I've recently seen how sanding tools can be used on materials that are powerful, such as stainless steel. From a Google search, it seems standard sanding tools are made out of materials like aluminum oxide, which (aluminum) I've generally understood to be a relatively weaker metal. I was hoping to get some clarification regarding the basic process of how the sandpaper does not deform itself, instead doing more damage to the material it's in contact with.

Comment: Aluminum oxide (also known as alumina or, in crystalline form sapphire) is a quite hard ceramic material, very different from aluminum. It has a Moh's hardness of 9.

Comment: That makes sense; so the material is definitely harder than most other metals that it comes in contact with

Comment: Yes, and if it doesn't work you go with diamond grit.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that also was an option. Seems a lot more expensive, though

Comment: You might be surprised how cheap diamond grit is - it isn't made from gem-quality diamonds. You can find it on Amazon or at Home Depot or other places. Quite standard for hard materials. Just checking, a 4 inch diamond grit pad (from 50 to 3000 grit to choose from) is about $10 each. Used for polishing stone (example - granite countertops).

Comment: I see; I suppose most of the value in diamonds is in the 3 C's, and diamond grit doesn't require those...

Comment: You may not be aware of this but two naturally occurring forms of aluminium oxide are ruby and sapphire both of which are very hard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure aluminum metal is relatively soft, but aluminum *oxide* is harder than any steel. The particles of the oxide that are glued to the paper have extremely sharp edges on them, and when you rub the sandpaper on a piece of steel, those sharp edges scrape off tiny pieces of steel.

Answer (score 1):

Aluminum oxide is easily hard enough to cut glass.  As a matter of fact, an aluminum oxide crystal with a small chromium oxide impurity is a ruby.  With a small titanium oxide impurity, it is a blue sapphire.